# $.get sends prototype functions in request URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have some prototype functions added to `Object` which in my opinion were practical in certain scenarios. However, I noticed that when I executed a $.get, the prototype functions are handled as data members and are sent like `http://...?prototypefunc=false`.

This is rather useless as I don't supply these as data members, but they *are* added to the query string.

To be exact, I have this code:

```
Object.prototype.in = function() {
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
       if(arguments[i] == this) return true;
    return false;
}

$.get('http://localhost/test.php', {'test': 'foo'}, function(text) { });
```

The corresponding URL constructed is:

`http://localhost/test.php?test=foo&in=false`

How can I avoid this?

Comment: And that is the reason why not to extend `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Why not? It's so useful in e.g. `foo.in(1,2,3)` to check whether foo is equal to 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @pimvdb: Because it might have side effects (as you can see). It is not that much more code to have `Helper.in(this, [1,2,3])`. Otherwise, the only way to fix your problem would be to edit the jQuery code.

Comment: @pim, it is like re-soldering and rewiring your motherboard and then find out it ain't compatible with the videocard any more....

Comment: I see, but until now it has worked like a charm. I prefer my solution using prototype, but if it results in things like `$.get` not working, I guess I'll have to change it...

Comment: @pimvdb: It is ok to do so as long as you have full control over the code. But as soon as you start using third party libraries, you don't have that control anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery runs a `for...in` loop on the object passed, which iterates over all enumerable properties of an object, whether inherited or not.  It doesn't do any checks to see if the object's property is owned by the object or inherited via the prototype chain.

Also, if it encounters a property whose value is a function during the serialization of the object it will execute the function and use the return value.

There are a few solutions:

- Change your code so that it doesn't modify `Object.prototype`.
- Pass a string instead of an object, or serialize the object to a string using your own code.
- Override the jQuery.param() function with your own, and force it to check each property with [`.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- Make the property on the prototype chain non-enumerable by using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (ECMAScript 5 compliant browsers only).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ideas, especially the last one, I didn't know about that function.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you dont't want to remove that in function, you should serialize data (with function, which works similary to jQuery **serialize**) to string and append it to URL.

Comment: @pimvdb: what do you mean? jQuery's serialization functions map to `$.param` under the hood, so you should get the same result.

Comment: @Ande E - my mistake, so that's why I edited and removed code with param function and voted up your answer. But pimvdb already read my answer - sorry for mess :/

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. I tested it in a new file, it indeed still returns the prototype function.

Comment: haha thanks for clearing that up, it did confuse me a little :-)